# Getting "ImportError: No Module named yaml" error

Tags: macos, yaml, ansible

Computer: MacBook Pro mid 2012, running El Capitan 10.11.4

Python version 2.7.10

I've been trying to install ansible from source, and I've run these two commands (following the steps on ansibles documentation):

```
git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
cd ./ansible
```

and then ran this

```
source ./hacking/env-setup
```

I've also already installed these packages

```
sudo pip install paramiko PyYAML Jinja2 httplib2 six
```

However, if I try and run ansible by typing it in the terminal, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/[myusr]/rock/ansible/bin/ansible", line 81, in <module>
from ansible.cli.adhoc import AdHocCLI as mycli
File "/Users/[myusr]/rock/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

What should be done here?

Answer (score 44):

Do you have yaml module installed? If not, try installing yaml using the following command:

```
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: ansible (2.2.0)
cffi (1.7.0)
cryptography (1.4)
Django (1.9.6)
enum34 (1.1.6)
Flask (0.10.1)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
idna (2.1)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
paramiko (2.0.1)
pip (1.5.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
PyYAML (3.11)
setuptools (23.1.0)
six (1.10.0)
vboxapi (1.0)
Werkzeug (0.11.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
yolk3k (0.9)
(from pip list)

Comment: Then the installation directory of yaml module is likely not in sys.path You can check it by importing sys and printing sys.path

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue. Got past it using @FranMowinckel's answer.

First I typed:

```
pip --version
```

it outputted python 3. But, when I tried:

```
sudo python -m pip install pyyaml
```

I got an error saying:

> Error: No module named pip

So, finally running:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

everything worked fine.
Go back and run:

```
sudo python -m pip install pyyaml
```

(you may have to run this with all the other modules as well)
Now you should finally be able to run your initial command which failed.

Answer (score 4):

For python 3.6 you can install it with

```
pip3 install pyyaml
```

if there is a problem in importing, do

```
pip3 uninstall pyyaml
```

and then install it again:

```
pip3 install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 3):

@bigdata2's answer is correct but it might also happen that there's a conflict with python 3. So, check pip version (`pip --version`) and if it outputs python 3 then:

```
sudo python -m pip install pyyaml
```

So it gets installed for the same version as python.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I installed it with

```
sudo pip install pyyaml --upgrade
```

instead of

```
sudo -H pip install pyyaml --upgrade
```

Uninstalling and re-installing pyyaml fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you explain why this command answer the question ?