# No module named yaml in python virtual env

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, virtualenv

I am using CentOS 6.4 with Python 2.6.6 to run Ansible 2.3.0. But when I go into my python virtual env which has python 3.4.1 and run "ansible --version" I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/namaaror/Desktop/githubansible/bin/ansible", line 80, in <module>
from ansible.cli.adhoc import AdHocCLI as mycli
File "/home/namanarora/Desktop/github/ansible/lib/cli/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
import yaml
ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I have even tried installing pyyaml by reffering [ImportError: No Module named yaml | Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131804/importerror-no-module-named-yaml-ansible)
but the error still persists. Is it somewhat related to yaml installation directory and sys.path?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: @techraf run ansible playbooks with python 3.4 in centos 6.4

Comment: Was your virtual env active when you run `pip install pyyaml`? If you ran it with `sudo` like in your ref, it was most probably not. Then try again without the `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

After you activate a virtualenv (via `ansible` or not) you should not have to use `sudo` to install something with `pip` as the whole virtualenv and all its directories are owned by you.

In fact if you use `sudo` you will probably not use the virtualenv's `pip`:

```
$ mktmpenv
Using real prefix '/opt/python/2.7'
New python executable in /home/venv/tmp-ef9b4ef621d87221/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'.
(tmp-ef9b4ef621d87221) $ which pip
/home/venv/tmp-ef9b4ef621d87221/bin/pip
(tmp-ef9b4ef621d87221) $ sudo which pip
[sudo] password for root: 
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

(the answer might be the same, depending on your login scripts and root's PATH). So you should not use `sudo pip install` when installing things  after activating the virtualenv, just use

```
pip install ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your python3 dist-packages directories /usr/local/lib/pythonX.XX/dist-packages to see if pyyaml is installed there.

If they aren't there, you can install them with `sudo apt-get install python3-yaml` (you might need python3-setuptools and python3-wheel as well)