# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyyaml'

Tags: python, pipenv, pyyaml, modulenotfounderror

**Installing the package**

I'm getting this error after trying all the following:

1. `pip3 install pyyaml`
2. Setup a virtualenv using pipenv and install it there
3. sudo
4. Install v5.1
5. `sudo python3 -m pip install pyyaml`

The library in all cases seem to be properly installed.

```
$ pip3 show pyyaml
Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.4.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://pyyaml.org/
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

In case of pipenv the location is
`Location: /Users/<username>/.local/share/virtualenvs/webwatch-zMzxdqeP/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

**Usage**

In the application I simply `import pyyaml`
and run it using either `python3 <myapp>.py` or doing the same thing using pipenv shell.

**Result**

On all cases `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyyaml'`

**More info**

```
$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
16 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 Aug 10  2020 /usr/bin/python3
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Jun 15  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

References:

1. https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/291
2. [Getting "ImportError: No Module named yaml" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131804/getting-importerror-no-module-named-yaml-error)
3. https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/590

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple and I'm surprised nobody has answered this yet: You just used the wrong name in the `import` statement.

The package is called **PyYAML** (see [pip](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) or the [homepage](https://pyyaml.org/)), and so you indeed install it using:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

***However***, the Python package to import is called **yaml**.

So instead of:

```py
import pyyaml
```

you should do:

```py
import yaml
```

This can be seen in the examples in the [tutorial](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#tutorial).

Note that the three references you included in your question are about another error message, so they are not really relevant for this question.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

same problem: since I installed python jupyter .. with miniconda3, I tried with conda install pyyaml and that's ok now.